# Loading the mtl colors from an 3D model in the Wavefront .obj format using Silk.NET.Assimp

Tags: c#, .net, assimp

I've written a model loader for 3D models in the Wavefront obj format in C# using the Silk.Net Assimp-Bindings.

I used the code from the opengl tutorials (Tutorial 4.1) provided by the Silk.Net-Framework as a foundation.

So far everything works (loading vertices, normals, textures ...). But now i want to get the mesh material colors from the mtl-File.

Using the C++ version of assimp i would simply call the `aiGetMaterialColor` function passing an `AI_MATKEY_COLOR_XXXXX` type as parameter for the color type i would like to get.

E.g.:

```
aiColor4 diffuse;
aiGetMaterialColor(material, AI_MATKEY_COLOR_DIFFUSE, &diffuse);
```

How do i do the same thing using Silk.Net.Assimp?

So far i have:

```
// get material
Material* material = scene->MMaterials[mesh->MMaterialIndex];

Vector4 diffuseColor = new Vector4();
this.assimp.GetMaterialColor(material, ...)
```

And now i am stuck which parameters should i pass to this function to get the material colors (ambient, diffuse, specular ...)? Is this even the right method to call or do i have to use another method?

The method itself has 21 overloads:

[Method overloads and parameters in Visual Studio](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Es1S9.jpg)